# where to find file /_layouts/CreateWebPage.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to create a custom content type in SharePoint 2010. To do this i need a document template. I want to use the excisting one (/_layouts/CreateWebPage.aspx) of a wiki page and modify it. Does anyone know where i can fint this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find it in the below folder:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS

What ever you change will be affected to all sites using that page.